# investigate the convergence of the sum of series?

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nn\tan\left(\pi/2^{n+1}\right)$$

I am confused on what to do. Do you maybe use the comparison rule?

Comment: First, you have to decide what $\tan(\pi/2^{n+1})$ is doing as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I believe my edit is what you meant by your question; correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: as n goes n to infinity tan (pi/2^(n+1) goes to zero. Then we have the undetermined case. How do I solve then.

Comment: Hint: $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}x=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\tan x\sim_0 x$ then

$$n\tan\left(\pi/2^{n+1}\right)\sim_\infty \frac{n\pi}{2^{n+1}}=o\left(\frac1 {n^2}\right)$$
so the given series is uncondionally convergent.